# Is there any way to count how many partitions reached in Spark query on Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I want to stop a Spark query if the query takes more than 10 mins.

But this is for just for one partition.

I mean if query reaches 2 partition in Hadoop so the time will be 20 mins.

For example, for this I need a 10 mins threshold:

```sql
SELECT Max(col1),
       Min(col2)
FROM   my_parititoned_table_on_hadoop
WHERE  partitioned_column = 1
```

For this I need a 20 mins threshold:

```sql
SELECT Max(col1),
       Min(col2)
FROM   my_parititoned_table_on_hadoop
WHERE  partitioned_column IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in your title (*"Is there any way to count how many partitions..."*) is a "yes" if your data is stored as parquet. You can run `explain()` on your query and see how many partitions will be scanned during query execution. For example

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from tab where p > '1' and p <'4'").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan parquet default.tab[id#375,desc#376,p#377] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, 
     Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ns1/user/hive/warehouse/tab/p=2, hdfs://ns1/user/hive/warehouse..., 
     **PartitionCount: 2,** PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(p#377), (p#377 > 1), (p#377 < 4)], 
     PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,desc:string>
```

...from which `PartitionCount: x` can be parsed quite easily.

The second question (which is technically a **statement** -- *"I want to stop a Spark query if the query takes more than 10 mins"*) is a "no", just as  @thebluephantom said.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such support in Spark.

And there is AQE that for some queries may alter the number of partitions / tasks on the fly? What would that mean?

Comment: which of the two questions are you answering? :)

Comment: 2 for the price of 1. I think you misread